# Is there a reliable profiler working for for Entity Framework 5?

Tags: profiling, entity-framework-5

I have used both *miniprofiler.ef* and glimpse for `EF` and `efprof.com` but at the time of writing all of them fail when working with `EF 5` (usually when working with spacial types).

Do you know any one that is reliable at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since December 2012 [EntityFramework profiler](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkProfiler) offers full EF 5 support (including spacial types)